# For every integer in a string I want to add an integer on - Python

Tags: python, list, ascii

I've converted a few sentences into ASCII and removed all the spaces too. But for everything in the string I want 20 to be added to it.

So now for each of the characters which are printed I need 20 to be added to each individual one. But I'm not sure how to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding `+ 20` somewhere? What happened? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. I'll edit my answer and provide an example.

Comment: `numbers = [1, 2, 3]`, `incremented = [n + 20 for n in numbers]`?

Comment: That works too thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
a = [83, 111, 109, 101, 119, 104, 101, 114, 101, 105, 110, 108, 97, 77, 97, 110, 99, 104, 97, 44, 105, 110, 97, 112, 108, 97, 99, 101, 119, 104, 111, 115, 101, 110, 97, 109, 101, 73, 100, 111, 110, 111, 116, 99, 97, 114, 101, 116, 111, 114, 101, 109, 101, 109, 98, 101, 114, 44, 97, 103, 101, 110, 116, 108, 101, 109, 97, 110, 108, 105, 118, 101, 100, 110, 111, 116, 108, 111, 110, 103, 97, 103, 111, 44, 111, 110, 101, 111, 102, 116, 104, 111, 115, 101, 119, 104, 111, 104, 97, 115, 97, 108, 97, 110, 99, 101, 97, 110, 100, 97, 110, 99, 105, 101, 110, 116, 115, 104, 105, 101, 108, 100, 111, 110, 97, 115, 104, 101, 108, 102, 97, 110, 100, 107, 101, 101, 112, 115, 97, 115, 107, 105, 110, 110, 121, 110, 97, 103, 97, 110, 100, 97, 103, 114, 101, 121, 104, 111, 117, 110, 100, 102, 111, 114, 114, 97, 99, 105, 110, 103, 46]
added_list = []
for item in a:
    added_list = added_list + [item+20]
print (added_list)
```

Comment: That works thanks. The first line is pretty long though. Is there anyway to condense it?

Answer (score 1):

If your ascii values are in a list, and you want the new values to be in another list, you can use the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function like this:

```
new_list = map(lambda x : x + 20, old_list)
```

Comment: When I printed it that happened. <map object at 0x00000000031F3898>

Comment: Can you tell me the the exact code that you ran, using the `convert` variable and the call to `map`

Comment: print("Enter the name of the file you would like to encrypt, ensuring you type .txt afterwards")
    filename=input()

    sample= open(filename, 'r').read()
    print(sample)  

    convert=[ord(c) for c in sample]   
    print("The following is your file converted into its corresponding ASCII value \n" +str(convert)+ "")

    for i in range (0,43):
    convert.remove(32)

    print ("New code \n" +str(convert)+ "")


    new_list = str(map(lambda x : x + 20, convert))

    print ("" +new_list+ "")

Comment: sorry I don't know why it's appearing like that. I indented it but it's not coming out right.

Comment: Original list was [97, 115, 100, 97, 115, 100, 97] and new list is [117, 135, 120, 117, 135, 120, 117]

Comment: that's really weird as it doesn't work on mine. But thanks for your help anyway. I'm just going to use Karthick P's as, although long, it worked. But thank you.

Comment: no problem, then you should accept his answer and upvote any others that were helpful

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to shift all the characters up by 20 to make a simple cypher. An alternative way of doing this would be to use a translation table:

```
s_from = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
s_to = 'uvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST'
cypher_table = str.maketrans(s_from, s_to)

print("Enter the name of the file you would like to encrypt, ensuring you type .txt afterwards")
filename = input()
sample = open(filename, 'r').read()
print(sample)
print()
print(sample.translate(cypher_table))
```

So if you input was `Abc`, it would give you `Uvw`. To reverse the process, you just need to swap `s_from` and `s_to` around.

Comment: Thanks for your input but this doesn't apply to the overall result of what I want my code to do but thank you anyway.